# Fragment instantiation using generic type, OnCreate method Doesn't call

Tags: java, android, generics, android-fragments, android-adapter

I have an adapter which create fragments this way :

```
public class FooAdapter<T extends Fragment> extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
   private Class<T> c;
   public FooAdapter(FragmentManager fm,Class<T> c) {
      super(fm);
      this.c = c;
   }

   @Override
   public Fragment getItem(int position) {
      try {
         T fragment = c.newInstance();
         return fragment;
      } catch (InstantiationException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
      return null;
   }
}
```

instantiation of the adapter:

```
new FooAdapter<BarFragment>(getSupportFragmentManager(),BarFragment.class)
```

I put logs in onCreate(and onAttach,onCreateView) of BarFragment but nothing logged !

```
public class BarFragment extends Fragment{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d(TAG, "on create view");
    }
}
```

Comment: are you assigning the adapter to the viewpager?

Comment: @zec yes I have assigned.

Comment: Both `getItem()` & `getCount()` need to be over-ridden.  So are you planning on only 1 adapter/viewpager per fragment?

Comment: yes I have overridden both of them .

Comment: I would suggest placing trace statements inside your adapter and see why your fragment isn't being created.  `Class<T>` looks suspect but only because I've never used it.  Other than that it seems like it should work.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, your onCreate method is wrong, you should use the onCreateView method and forget onCreate.

Something like this:

```
public class BarFragment extends Fragment{

    public BarFragment(){

    }

    @Override

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(LAYOUT YOU WANT TO INFLATE, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

I'l look more deeply into your adapter code now.

Comment: lol it's not wrong since they have just a log statement and i'm pretty sure this is all just a code snippet.

Comment: if BarFragment was extending FragmentActivity, that would be the correct way to do it. Because it's extending Fragment, you should use the onCreateView method. Source: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html

Comment: there you go pal - http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle